# Align Dropdown to right in bootstrap navbar

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I Need to Align just the Drop Down menu to the right end of the screen. I have tried adding  dropdown-menu-right mr-auto.

The drop down goes till the right of class="nav navbar-nav"> not till the end of the screen

```
<div class="container">

  <!-- Static navbar -->
  <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-default">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="offcanvas" data-target="#navbar-offcanvas" data-canvas="body">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-offcanvas offcanvas" id ="navbar-offcanvas">

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="../navmenu/">Slide in</a></li>
        <li><a href="../navmenu-push/">Push</a></li>
        <li><a href="../navmenu-reveal">Reveal</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="./">Off canvas navbar</a></li>

        <li class="dropdown ml-auto">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu  dropdown-menu-right mr-auto">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
```

Comment: It doesn't work because you're using Bootstrap 3 markup for Bootstrap 4. **[Read the docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/navbar/)**

Answer (score 0):

[Is this what you want?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2VE3.png)
It isn't clear if you want to solve this only with bootstrap, but i manage to make the dropdown go to the right using a css stylesheet: a `position=absolute` and `right=0` in the `li.dropdown` .

Comment: I have add li.dropdown
{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;

}  Still it does't work

Comment: You would have to creat a css file, link to it on the html with `<link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">`
The css would have:
    `li.dropdown {
       position:absolute;
       right:0;
   }`